# Microwave kiln for glass

Tags: diy, microwave

I am building a 1000W [microwave kiln for glass jewelry](https://www.google.com/search?q=microwave%20kiln%20for%20glass%20jewelry). The internal capacity needs to be around 5 litres. 
What internal dimensions of the cavity should I avoid, or strive for, to ensure even heating. 
Where should I locate the feedpoint, and. 
Would a magnetron feeding into such a small space be subject to an excessive load?

Comment: so, while microwave kilns use RF, they're not radios, and although it all boils down to Maxwell's equations, it's not a question about general radio technology or theory. This is engineering a specific heating device, so maybe ask this over at https://electronics.stackexchange.com .

Comment: (also, seriously, a 1000W microwave oven can, without being obvious, lead to permanent or even lethal damage (Ok, death is permanent, too) if built incorrectly, and you can only verify it's built correctly by using expensive microwave measurement equipment. This might be one of the rare cases where "if you have to ask, this project's a bit too dangerous for you" applies. There's microwave weapons with lower power.)

Comment: I am simply trying to downsize the physical dimensions of an existing household appliance! I just need to know just how small a cavity a domestic magnetron would operate in before it would be mismatched to the load imposed by a smaller than commercially used cavity!  It is not like I am trying to "weaponize" a Panasonic!!

Comment: @RJohnson The problem lies in how easy it is to *accidentally* "weaponize" that Panasonic.  Defeat one interlock, and it's very dangerous -- and I can see doing that accidentally, if you're poking around in the works.

Comment: "simply trying to downsize" but that involves a complete re-engineering of a microwave resonator cell. That's the majority of the RF design involved. "I'm just trying to replace the horses in front of a carriage with an electric motor" would be an analogy that comes to my mind.

Comment: Why do you want to make the cavity smaller? Size makes very little difference, all the energy is absorbed by the food or other load. Also how will you seal the smaller cavity? Kitchen microwaves have a cunning quarter wave choke that seals the oven without electrical contact (which would get dirty and rust etc.)

Comment: Before we closed this, I added a link. There appears to be microwave kilns available for glass jewelry for about 40 bucks. Also, as others here have stated, this is not likely to work. *Microwaves are a completely different animal than HF, VHF, and UHF*. **Also**, think about this: running a common kitchen microwave oven without a load (a larger mass that gets hot) will ruin it. **Either glass jewelry has enough of a load, or there is something different about a microwave kiln.** Just tryin' to help you. :-)

Comment: Yes, there is a circular ceramic waveguide that is placed in the oven. This concentrates the energy into a small area within the center. Acting as the load and converting the microwave energy into heat which then melts the glass. I was simply trying to reduce the size to fit available space. Looks like I will just have to make the available space bigger!!

Comment: There's no RF magic in a microwave glass (or metal) kiln. I googled: How do microwave kilns work?
The kiln is made of a white insulating fiber and lined on the inside of the chamber with a black compound that absorbs the microwave radiation and heats up to 1650°F. The heat from this compound is then transferred to the chamber and to the piece being fired. Fair enough to want to shrink your microwave oven, but it's a lot of work.

Comment: I agree. Not worth the effort. I can see a cheap microwave from the second hand shop coming soon!